# Get split value from two zip list

Tags: python-3.x

i have this two lists and i need to zip them and then i need to get one of the values

```
for x in heapq.nlargest(5, zip(list1,list2)):     
    print("->: ",x)
```

> This prints ->: (9.99, 'SFO-RE.0025')

I need to get the 9.99 in order to run it thru another function evval('9.99')

I was hopping that someone could help me get this value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`heapq.nlargest` returns a list, so use `x[0]` to get the first item in `x`.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html

https://realpython.com/lessons/indexing-and-slicing/